# discord.js - Code doesn't destroy all channels because the loop is incorrectly typed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

despite my attempts to fix the code and researching, my command that deletes all channels refuses to do execute and simply prints text in command line. Here's the current source code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < message.guild.channels;) {
message.guild.channels.delete[i];
}
console.log('all channels got deleted!');
```

All i ask is, is `i` incorrectly typed? Is `message.guild...` incorrect typed and correct order? Are there missing code? Is the loop correct? I've been reading Discord.js documentation and don't understand some of properties in Channel page. I'd appreciate help

Edit:forgot to inform i am using v12

Comment: In general, it is useful to put as much relevant information as possible, not just to specify  the version, unless it's a well known npm package, but also then, it's useful to specify that it's an npm package, but in this case you have a javascript error, that has nothing to do with the discord implementation, so your question could better portray the answer you want to get

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to delete all channels in a guild is the following:

```
guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
```

Answer (score 1):

## The Short Answer

1: You are missing the `i++` in the `for` loop.

2: If you are looping a list of channels, then you need to get the channel via the subscript, and call it's delete method

```
for (let i = 0; i < message.guild.channels.length; i++) {
   message.guild.channels[i].delete();
}
```

## Nevertheless

All of the above is just the JavaScript Syntax and how to work with loops and arrays, but from the [DiscrodJs](https://discord.js.org/) docs, it looks like the
`guild` object, does not contain a list of channels, but a [GuildChannelManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels)
which seams to handle the channels, but it's unclear if you can actually iterate over the channels the way you are trying, so you should check that as well, you might be trying to do something that's actually impossible

Answer (score 0):

Your *for* loop is wrong; you forgot to increase *i* after the code block is executed:

```js
for(...; i++) {
//...
}
```

Also, you used square brackets instead of parantheses in the delete method.